# Is it possible to query nested json object using TinyDB

Tags: python, json, tinydb

I have JSON file having following structure

```
{  
     "type":[  
        "apple-shimle",
        "king"
     ],

     "json-object":{  
        "test":"hi"
     }
  }
```

How to search for test == "hi" using TinyDB python only. Iam able to fetch "json-object" using search() but not "test".

Comment: Can you show us what you got so far? The code, I mean.

Comment: @franciscosollima here is the code i tried to find "json-object"

db.search(Check['json-object'].exists())  it returned  {'type': ['apple-shimle', 'king'], 'json-object': {'test': 'hi'}}

Now iam actually interested in existence of "test" so,
 db.search(Check['test'].exists())    this returned [ ], means not exist
I tried this because i know mongodb checks inside nested json object.

Comment: Try `db.search(Check['json-object']['test'].exists())`

Answer (score 0):

As [from the docs](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#queries) you can query nested fields like this:

```
db.search(Check['json-object']['test'].exists())
```